# ASP.NET MVC DEPLOY

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, deployment

I deployed my application on IIS following the instructions in  `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_LM24wOWMIU`, but on url `http://demo.local` there is an error `HTTP 403.14 — Forbidden`. How can I deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try any of the following methods to resolve this error.

Method 1: Enable the Directory Browsing feature in IIS (recommended)

1. Start IIS Manager.
2. To do it, select Start, select Run, type
   inetmgr.exe, and then select OK.
3. In IIS Manager, expand server name,
   expand Web sites, and then select the website that you want to
   change. In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
4. In the Actions pane, select Enable.

Method 2: Add a default document

1. Start IIS Manager. To do it, select Start, select Run, type inetmgr.exe, and then
   select OK.
2. In IIS Manager, expand server name, expand Web sites, and then select the website
   that you want to change.
3. In the Features view, double-click Default Document.
4. In the Actions pane, select Enable.
5. In the File Name box, type the name of the default document, and then select OK.